# Passing the value of a variable from one js file to another

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

There is a file `js` in which there is a variable. You need to pass the value of this variable to another `js` file. How can this be realized?

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var bal = document.getElementById('bal').value;
  console.log(bal);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="bal">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Send">
```

That's how I take the value of the variable in the first file.In your menu there is input, this js file is responsible for reading the value of the input and sending it to another js file which will do something with the data it receives, say on google.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are working on any webpage then you are including all the js file in your web page. In this case there is no meaning of different js file. When you includes a js file to any webpage you can access any method or variable from anywhere unless you declare that variable inside any function or class.

for example 
you are including two file with script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/test2.js"></script>
```

This line is declared in one file.

```
  var tst = "This line is from one js file";
```

This line from another file which is calling "tst" varible.

```
 console.log("This is anoter js file calling that variable "+tst);
```

Comment: this is extension, I need two files: one for the extension menu, and the second for running the script on the page

Comment: you are including two file with script tag.   
This line is declared in one file.
::   var tst = "This line is from one js file";

This line from another file which is calling "tst" varible.

:: console.log("This is anoter js file calling that variable "+tst);

Answer (score 0):

Create the variable in the global scope , now you can use it in any file you want in the same page

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code into a module (e.g. *bal.js*):

```
 export default function(cb){
   document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
      var bal = document.getElementById('bal').value;
      console.log(bal);
      cb(bal);
   };
 };
```

So now in another file you can do:

```
 import bal from "bal.js";
 bal(res => alert(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session storage to store the value and retrieve it in next file

In first file

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', document.getElementById('bal').value);
```

In another js file

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

Comment: create 4 separate keys

Comment: thx, one more: when I go to the page the variable is null because the value of the variable comes later than it starts to be used. How can this be remedied?